# How can I setup reverse DNS for a home SMTP server?

Tags: server, dns, smtp, postfix-mta

I am running Postfix MTA on my home server to send bulk emails.I have setup MX records and DNS but rDNS still needs to be configured as gmail etc. won't accept email from my IP. I don't have a VPS so I can't use cPanel or WHM. Is there any other alternative.

NOTE: I can't use a mail provider like gmail as I need to send more than 500 emails daily.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're managing your own DNS (using BIND9, for example) you'll need to create a reverse zone file and add a line to your named.conf.

Comment: You have to ask your ISP to do it for you (which I doubt they will do for a home connection)

Comment: @kimbo That is the easy part... the complex part would be to get the proper delegation from the authority on this IP address block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse IP address is linked with the PTR record set by the owner of the IP address which is mostly your ISP. You need to check with your ISP (Internet Service Provider) on updating the PTR record for the IP address assigned to you.